# Why am I getting a runtime error?

Tags: string, divide-and-conquer

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int find(char a[],int p,int q,char t){
int l=strlen(a);
int k,m,n;
if(p==q){
  if(a[0]==t)return 1;
     else return 0;}
  if(p<q){
     int mid=p+q/2;
     m=find(a,p,mid,t);
     n=find(a,mid+1,q,t);
     if(m>n)return m;
     else 
       return n;
        }
     if(p>q)return 0;
      }

int main()
{
int test,j,k,i,l,s=0;
char a[200],tc='a';
scanf("%d",test);
while(test--){
s=0;
tc='a';
scanf("%d",&a);
l=strlen(a);
if(l<26){
    printf("NO\n");
    continue;
}
for(i=1;i<=26;i++){
    j=find(a,0,l,tc);
    if(j==1)s++;
    tc++;
}
if(s==26)printf("YES");
else printf("NO\n");
}
return 0;
}
```

The question was:A string is said to be complete if it contains all the characters from a to z. Given a string, check if it complete or not.I tried the divide and conquer technique.Why am I getting a runtime error?

Answer (score 2):

You have missed some braces. I put the entire code here, for a better understanding.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int find(char a[],int p,int q,char t)
{
 int l=strlen(a);
 int k,m,n;
 if(p==q)
 {
   if(a[0]==t)return 1;
   else return 0;
 }
 if(p<q){
 int mid=p+q/2;
 m=find(a,p,mid,t);
 n=find(a,mid+1,q,t);
 if(m>n){
         return m;
         }
 }
 else{
      return n;
     }
 if(p>q)
 {
      return 0;
 }
}

int main()
{
int test,j,k,i,l,s=0;
char a[200],tc='a';
scanf("%d",test);
while(test--){
s=0;
tc='a';
scanf("%d",&a);
l=strlen(a);
if(l<26){
printf("NO\n");
continue;
}
for(i=1;i<=26;i++){
  j=find(a,0,l,tc);
if(j==1)s++;
tc++;
}
  if(s==26)
     { 
     printf("YES");
     }
  else{
     printf("NO\n");
    }
}
 system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd add some printf to your find function to check that it correctly applies the divide and conquer.

To me, your mid calculation looks wrong:

```
int mid=p+q/2;
```

should be

```
int mid=p+((q-p)/2);
```